# Prevent second click when data is still in loading

Tags: jquery

I have a link in my page, when user click on this link I will load some data with `$.getJSON` and if the server was busy or the internet speed connection was low, this response will take about 10 seconds, so may be user click again on this link, how can I change my code to prevent the second click ? I mean is, how can I define if user click for second time on link, do not anything ?

this is click event :

```
$('#showResult').click(function () {
     $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {

        .... MY CODE ....

     });
});
```

Sorry for my bad English :-(

Comment: you can disable the button, and when success get data, you enable it

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this :

```
$('#showResult').click(function () {
     var _this = this;
     if (this.inprogress) {
         alert('please wait');
         return;
     }
     this.inprogress = true;
     $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {

        .... MY CODE ....
        _this.inprogress= false;
     });
});
```

But usually I prefer to have a progress spinner displayed and the whole window greyed when I have a long loading in progress, so that the user knows he has to wait :

```
loading = {
    count: 0
};

loading.finish = function() {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count==0) this.$div.hide();
};

loading.start = function() {
    this.count++;
    if (!this.$div) {
        var html = '<div style="position: fixed;z-index:100;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background: black;opacity: 0.6;">'; // this class covers and greys the whole page
        html += '<table width=100% height=100%>';
        html += '<tr><td align=center valign=middle>';
        html += '<img src=img/loading.gif>';
        html += '</td></tr>';
        html += '</table></div>';
        this.$div=$(html);
        this.$div.prependTo('body');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (loading.count>0) loading.$div.show();
    }, 500);
};

$('#showResult').click(function () {
     loading.start();
     $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {

        .... MY CODE ....

        loading.finish();
     });
});
```

(with this code, the spinner is displayed only if the ajax call takes more than 500 ms).

Answer (score 1):

You can try unbinding the click, like

```
$('#showResult').click(function () {
     $(this).unbind("click");
     $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {

        .... MY CODE ....
        //after response data you can rebind it

     });
});
```

OR
you can add some attribute and check on it, like add "clicked" as data after one click

```
$('#showResult').click(function () {
     if($(this).data("clicked") {
         return false;
     }
     else {
       $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {

        .... MY CODE ....
        $('#showResult').data("clicked", true);
       });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should **capture a double click** on the element and prevent that event from bubbling up.

```
$("#showResult").on('dblclick',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you simply want to prevent a second click on the element while some other action is happening, you can use a boolean flag.  Something like `isWorking`.

```
var isWorking = false;

$("#showResult").on('click',function(){
  if (!isWorking){
    //execute code here!
    isWorking = true;
  }else{
    // wait! something is still working!
  }
});
```

Don't forget to return your flag to it's original position after the action has completed.

`isWorking = false;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var doJson = function(doCallback) {
     $('#showResult').unbind('click');
     $.getJSON (url, data, function updateForm() {
        .... MY CODE ....
        doCallback();
     });
}

$('#showResult').click(function () {
    doJson(function() {
        $('#showResult').bind('click', this));
    });
});
```

The callback binds the function, the function unbinds it :)